# How can I send current culture to my Grpc Server in c#?

Tags: c#, grpc

What is the best practice in order to send my current culture from Grpc Client to Grpc Server in a c# project using dotnetcore3?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do it by adding the culture to the headers and with an Interceptor:

```
public class ThreadCultureInterceptor : Interceptor
{
    public override async Task<TResponse> UnaryServerHandler<TRequest, TResponse>(
        TRequest request,
        ServerCallContext context,
        UnaryServerMethod<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
    {
        var headerLanguage = context.RequestHeaders.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Key == "language");
        if (headerLanguage != null)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(headerLanguage.Value);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(headerLanguage.Value);
        }

        return await continuation(request, context);
    }
}
```

In your Startup.cs:

```
services.AddGrpc(options =>
{
    options.Interceptors.Add<ThreadCultureInterceptor>();
});
```

On your client application:

```
var credentials = CallCredentials.FromInterceptor((context, metadata) =>
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginResponse.Token))
    {
        metadata.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {loginResponse.Token}");
        metadata.Add("Language", "en-US");
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
});

channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001", new GrpcChannelOptions
{
    Credentials = ChannelCredentials.Create(new SslCredentials(), credentials)
});
client = channel.CreateGrpcService<IService>();
```

Answer (score -1):

Read about [CultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8). This class holds a string property called `Name`. Commonly you just need to access the current context by doing `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`.

You can also define your own culture in the server and client by setting a value on `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`.

Ex:

```cs
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Comment: That's fine, but my question is what is the correct way to send that culture from my client to the grpc server? example: header, additional parameter. My intention is not to break any standards, but I cannot find this topic in the documentation.

Comment: Best practice is really subjective. As long as it doesn't pose any security risk on your end you should be good to go.

Comment: @vicosanz I think you are being consumed by an irrelevant problem. Header/Parameter, either will work and either is the right answer. There's no significant benefit either way.